# SML: Trouble Tracing Sieve Function

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm a bit confused by a function to find primes.  I'm given the following:

```
fun divides x y = (y mod x = 0);

fun sieve [] = []
    | sieve(x::L) = x::sieve(filter (not o (divides x)) L);
```

Within `sieve`, I know that divides `x` is a partial application of `divides`.  It just returns a function that checks whether whatever is passed to it is divisible by `x`.

Suppose I call `sieve([2, 3, 4, ..., 10])`.

Then on the first recursive call, I'd get

```
2::sieve(filter(not o (divides 2)) [3, 4, 5, ..., 10])

2::sieve([3, 5, 7, 9])

2::3::sieve(filter(not o (divides 3)) [5, 7, 9])

2::3::sieve([5, 7])

2::3::5::sieve(filter(not o (divides 5)) [7])

2::3::5::7
```

Does this look right?

Thanks for checking,

bclayman

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct (though your final line should read `2::3::5::7::[]`). This code seems to be an SML modification of a [famous piece of Haskell code](http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_(Haskell)). In the Haskell version, `primes` is defined as a lazy list which is conceptually infinite (end then e.g. `take 100 primes` would give you the first 100 primes). The link I gave above has a nice explanation of the basic logic (which doesn't depend heavily on lazy lists). There are various ways you can implement lazy lists in SML. For fun you might want to try to make an SML version which is closer to the Haskell version.